# Django TestCase assert query returns object

Tags: django, unit-testing

Not sure why I can't find documentation on this but:

```
    def test_invalid_trip_location_field_value(self):
        trip_location_field = TripLocationField.objects.filter(
            name='Fiji'
        ).first()
        self.assertEqual(len(trip_location_field), 1)
```

This gives me `TypeError: object of type 'TripLocationField' has no len()`. How can I assert that the object exists?

Comment: TripLocationField.objects.filter(name='Fiji').count() try this..!

Comment: What if i need the object loaded into memory?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `first()` returns a `TripLocationField` object that you defined in `models.py`. It doesn't make any sense to call `len()` on ONE object because it isn't a collection of any kind.

So don't call `first()`:

```
trip_location_fields = TripLocationField.objects.filter(name='Fiji')`
```

Now you get a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/) object that you can call [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) on to find the number of objects:

```
self.assertEqual(trip_location_fields.count(), 1)
```

Note that this test seems like you are testing that Django works like it says it does. While this is a good exercise for learning, I recommend that you write tests that verify code that you wrote. In particular, this means that you should call a function in your own code or use the Django test clien to make a request to one of your endpoints as part of your test. Then you can assert that the function or endpoint you called does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Assuming that an object exists is not testing that Django works like it says it does. It's testing that data you need for the test is in the database. But thanks. I just think it's odd that a `assertObjectExists` method doesn't exist. It's also annoying that i now need to subsequently call `.first()` on the query in order to have my object in memory.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Out of curiosity, how is the object created?

Comment: Fixtures, which is why I would need to make sure it exists in case fixtures change. But I see your point.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Reading [the docs for `first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#first), I see that it returns `None` if there are no objects in the queryset. This means you can `self.assertIsNotNone(trip_location_field)` in your original version. If your concern is that an object exists, this may be sufficient, but it won't help if there are more than one of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Code-Apprentice notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77995498/67579), your `.first()` will return a model *object*, or `None` if no such object can be found. We thus can check with `None`.

We can however make it more convenient by defining our own test that we can then use everywhere:

```
def assertQuerySetContains(qs, msg=None):
    self.assertIsNotNone(
        qs.first(), msg or f'{qs} should contain at least one item'
    )
```

then we can test this with:

```
def test_invalid_trip_location_field_value(self):
    self.assertQuerySetContains(TripLocationField.objects.filter(name='Fiji'))
```